# Distorted font in Chrome Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, fonts, ubuntu-16.04

I just updated chrome on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Most of the font on pages opened in Chrome looks distorted. Anyone having same issues?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try to install the Chromium Browser.

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

The Chromium Browser runs like Google Chrome.
Make a test and tell us how the fonts are exhibited.

Bye.